# How do you give non-root permissions when creating a volume with docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, user-permissions

I'm using Docker Desktop with WSL2 and I'm having trouble with the fact that some of my container using a non-root user can't create or paste file in a volume.

It seems that when creating a volume with `docker-compose`, it automatically gives root ownership to it.

Is there a way to change permissions of the volume or to allow non-root user to write in it?

Docker version below:

```yaml
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.2
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:00:27 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:07:04 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Comment: You have to set correct owner id, group id for mounted volume from outside the container. For example if your mount argument is: `-v /external/folder:/container/internal/folder`, and `UID`, `GID` of container user is `1000`, then you have to run `sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /etxternal/folder`

Comment: That's true for bind mounts, but it's not true for Docker volumes. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 4):

If you create a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  example:
    image: myimage
    volumes:
      - ./host/path:/container/path
```

Then the directory in the container will have whatever ownership and permissions the directory has on your host filesystem. As @rzlvmp points out in a comment, you can adjust the directory permissions as necessary to match the requirements of your container.

If you mount a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/):

```
version: "3"

services:
  example:
    image: myimage
    volumes:
      - myvolume:/container/path

volumes:
  myvolume:
```

The volume will be inherit the permissions of the target directory in the container. If your image was created from a `Dockerfile` that includes something like:

```
RUN useradd myuser; mkdir -p /container/path; chown myuser /container/path
```

Then the directory in the running container would look like:

```
root@d268cf1fcd7c:/# ls -ld /container/path
drwxr-xr-x. 2 myuser root 6 May 23 03:42 /container/path
```

---

From the above, you can see that using named volumes is going to be the easiest way to manage storage: you get a directory with appropriate permissions without requiring any special initialization scripts or any sort of elevated privileged in the container.

If you're in the rare situation in which a named volume isn't appropriate, one option is to include an `ENTRYPOINT` script, running as `root`, that ensures the correct permissions on your directories before executing the main command as an unprivileged user.  That is, create a `Dockerfile` that includes:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And in `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

chown -R myuser /container/path

exec runuser -u nonrootuser "$@"
```

This works, but requires that your container start as root in order to change permissions (and if you're working with an existing image this requires that you take into account any existing entrypoint script).